# Why does this regular expression work?

Tags: regex

OK I'm thoroughly on *why* this regular expression works.  The text I'm working with is this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    hello
    <img src="withalt" alt="hi"/>asdf
    <img src="noalt" />fdsa<a href="asdf">asdf</a>
    <img src="withalt2" alt="blah" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the following regular expression (tested in php but I'm assuming it's true for all perl regular expressions), it will return all img tags which do not contain an alt tag:

```
/<img(?:(?!alt=).)*?>/
Returns:
<img src="noalt" />
```

So based on that I would think that simply removing the no backreference would return the same:

```
/<img(?!alt=).*?>/
Returns:
<img src="withalt" alt="hi"/>
<img src="noalt" />
<img src="withalt2" alt="blah" />
```

As you see instead it just returns all image tags.  Then to make things even more confusing, removing the ? (simply a wildcard as far as I'm aware) after the * returns up to the final >

```
/<img(?!alt=).*>/
Returns:
<img src="withalt" alt="hi"/>
<img src="noalt" />fdsa<a href="asdf">asdf</a>
<img src="withalt2" alt="blah" />
```

So anyone care to inform me, or at least point me in the right direction of what's going on here?

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Comment: Hah, that html was just something I wrote up real quick to test out someone else's regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/<img(?:(?!alt=).)*?>/
```

This regex applies *negative look-ahead* for each character it matches after `img`. So, as soon as it finds `alt=`, it stops. So, it will only match the `img` tag, that does not have an `alt` attribute.

```
/<img(?!alt=).*?>/
```

This regex, just applies the *negative look-ahead* after `img`. So, it will match everything till the first `>` for all the `img` tag which is not followed by `alt=`, no matter whether `alt=` appears anywhere further down the string. It will be covered in `.*?`

```
/<img(?!alt=).*>/
```

This is same as the previous one, but it matches everything till the last `>`, since it uses `greedy matching`. But I don't know why you got that output. You should have got everything till the last `>` for `</html>`.

---

Now forget everything that happened there, and move towards an `HTML Parser`, for parsing an `HTML`. They are specifically designed for this task. So, don't bother using regex, because you can't parse every kind of HTML's through regex.

Comment: so what you're saying is the second (non-greedy) regex is matching everything until the first >, then verifying that the entire .* does not begin with alt=.  So ok that all makes sense.  As for the greediness, I'm going to have to brush up on that because it seems to be a lot more in depth than I remember.  Thanks!

Comment: @Eric. No, it first verifies that `img` is not followed by an `alt=`, and then only it moves ahead with further matching everything till the first `>`.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense since it's a look-ahead and not look-behind.   Also a lot more useful as far as the speed of the regular expression.  Oh and I think the reason why the third regex didn't match all the way up to the </html> is because of php's preg_match_all() function.  If I remember right it just does matching line by line.

Comment: @Eric. Ok. No idea about `preg_match_all()`. Not a PHP guy here. :)